# Why won't doGet run processRequest?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jdbc, javadb

The way that the program is supposed to work is that there is a javaDB in the background that the servlet can pull from.  The servlet gets a keyword from index.jsp and uses that to search the DB to get the information related to that keyword.  But the doGet method is not even attempting to run anything in a try/catch block.  I know the doGet method is running because I have tried loading test code in there and it does display it, just will not run through the try/catch.

DBConnector.java

```
package edu.uwf.cs.dsa;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
/**
 *
 * @author Bernd
 */

public class DBConnector extends HttpServlet {

    private Context env;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config)
            throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        try {
            env = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ServletException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String getUrl() throws NamingException 
    {
            return (String)env.lookup("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/JA112");
    }

    private Connection getConnection() 
            throws NamingException, ServletException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
            Class.forName((String)env.lookup("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"));
            return DriverManager.getConnection(getUrl());
    }

    private void getMovies(Connection conn, PrintWriter out) throws SQLException
    {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from Student");
            while (rs.next()) {
                out.print(rs.getString(1)); out.println("<br />");
                out.print(" " + rs.getString(2)); out.println("<br />");
                out.print(" " + rs.getString(3)); out.println("<br />");
                out.print(" " + rs.getString(4)); out.println("<br />");
                out.println(" " + rs.getString(5)); out.println("<br />");
            }
    }
    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, NamingException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection conn = getConnection();

      //  out.print("<html>\n <head>\n <body>\n<h1>test</h1>\n</body>\n</head>\n</html>");

        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet DBConnector</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet DBConnector at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println((String)env.lookup("driver")); 
            out.println("<br />");
            out.println(getUrl()); 
            out.println("<br />");
            out.println(conn);
            getMovies(conn,out);
            out.println("<br />");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Nov 21, 2012, 9:20:16 PM
    Author     : Bernd
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="/DBServlet/DBConnector">
            <h1>Movie Search</h1>
            Enter Keyword <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How `DBConnector` defined in web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the `env` variable it's been initialized to null in normal testing, you need to add the catch block on the `processRequest()` method so it will became clear this is the error, for now you only have the finally block, so the Exception it's hidden and unclear.

Once you add the block and see the exception, you'll need to check your config file where you defined the `java:comp/env` , maybe a typo or something like that could be causing the real problem.